# Esri JavaScript ArcGIS API - Developing a FeatureMap Attributes Filter Widget

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, widget

I'm currently trying to develop a FeatureMap Attributes Filter for Esri basemap with a featuremap on top of it, but I am struggling with some of the new stuff as I am fairly new to this type of programming (Python, data arrays analyst here).

My problem and question:

- How do I input my current FeatureMap so the widget knows what to analyse?

Here is my widget code:

```
/////////////////// Widget
@subclass("FilterWidget")
class FilterWidget extends declared(Widget) {
  constructor(params?: any) {
    super();
  }

  // Variable input for the filtering
  @property()
  @renderable()
  FirstAttribute: string;

  // Variable input for the filtering
  @property()
  @renderable()
  SecondAttribute: string;

  // Variable input for the filtering
  @property()
  @renderable()
  ThirdAttribute: string;

   define the property dependencies
  @property()
   readOnly: true;
   dependsOn: ["FirstAttribute", "SecondAttribute", "ThirdAttribute"];

  //// Drop-down menu layout
  render() {
    var sqlExpressions = ["ID > 0", this.FirstAttribute, this.SecondAttribute, this.ThirdAttribute];

       var selectFilter = document.createElement("select");
       selectFilter.setAttribute("class", "esri-widget esri-select");
       selectFilter.setAttribute("style", "width: 275px; font-family: Avenir Next W00; font-size: 1em;");

       sqlExpressions.forEach(function(sql){
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.value = sql;
         option.innerHTML = sql;
         selectFilter.appendChild(option);
       });
       //view.ui.add(selectFilter, "top-right");

  //// Filtering computation
       function setFeatureLayerViewFilter(expression: any) {
           view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(featureLayerView: any) {
             featureLayerView.filter = {
               where: expression
             };
           });
         }

       selectFilter.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
       setFeatureLayerViewFilter((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
     });

     return (
      <div class="browser esri-widget esri-widget--panel">
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export = FilterWidget;
```

and here is the following I write in my main.ts file to call the widget

```
var filterByEjer = new FilterWidget({
  FirstAttribute: "Ejer = 'Ejer'",
  SecondAttribute: "Ejer = 'Uoplyst'",
  ThirdAttribute: "Ejer = 'Kommunal'"
});

view.ui.add(filterByEjer, "top-right");
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One Question per Question. Please [Edit] you question so it asks your most pressing question; other questions can be asked later.

Comment: @Vince thank you. I have now done the edit :-)